# How do I adjust the Windows 11 Touch Screen sensitiviy?

Tags: windows-11, touchscreen

My new HP Envy X360 laptop's touch screen is not very sensitive.
When I try to use a passive stylus (Pen) it often "skips" as if the screen isn't reading it.

Is there a setting for ts sensitivity?

Comment: Sensitivity of capacitive screens is set in hardware or firmware. No way to change it.

Comment: Did you check the instructions at https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/ish_4305073-3491276-16 ?

Comment: Ask HP Support and possibly suggest returning it.

Comment: HP Support had no idea. referred me to paid support. Yes, I'll just return it if I can't resolve it.